# Delete duplicated files using python

Tags: python

I am trying to delete duplicated files on my disk but I'm stuck.

I made a new class containing 3 fields: path, size and filename:

```
class photo:
   def __init__(self, path, size):
      self.path = re.sub(r'.*\\', '', path)
      self.size = size
      self.hash = self.path+self.size
   def getTitle(self):
       return (self.path)
   def getSize(self):
       return (self.size)
   def getHash(self):
       return (self.hash)
```

Then, I add all files to a list:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
for name in [f for f in files if f.endswith(".jpg")]:
   title = os.path.join(path, name)
   size = str(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path, name)))
   photo_list.append(photo(title, size))
```

All I need now is to extract duplicated files, for example when I have something like this:
c:\example.jpg
c:\subdir\example.jpg

I need to extract this to some other list like duplicated_list, in the next step I will choose which one I delete.

Comment: I hope you have backups for when this goes wrong!

Comment: As an aside, if you are learning Python, you don't need to write getters and setters. Just access the attributes directly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service.

Comment: What stops you from doing just what you describe?  There are many Python tutorials and examples on line; before you post here, you should have a coding attempt at your problem.  Sticking things in a list, iterating over a list, and comparing items, are all basic programming skills.  When you have an honest attempt with a problem, *then* you have somethign to post to Stack Overflow.